# convergence of random elements taking values from the subspace of normed space

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let us consider some normed space $\mathcal{X}$ endowed with Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}_{x}$. Next, let $\mathcal{Y} \subset \mathcal{X}$ be a subset of $\mathcal{X}$, endowed with Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}_{y}$.

Next, let $\{y_{n}\}_{n}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables defined on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B}_{x})$, but taking values at $\mathcal{Y}$, a.s., and assume that in $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B}_{y})$ we have
$$
y_{n} \overset{a.s.}{\to} y.
$$

Can we then say that
$$
y_{n} \overset{a.s.}{\to} y
$$
in $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B}_{x})$?

Comment: If you actually mean "let $\{y_{n}\}_{n}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables defined *on* $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B}_{y})$" then the answer to your question is of course not, $y_n$ is not an element of $Y$. BUT the title indicates that this is _not_ what you mean. Which is it, defined on $Y$ or taking values in $Y$??????

Comment: sorry, by mistake I sent a draft at the first time. I have changed it.

Comment: The third version finally made sense (*if* "at $Y$" means "in $Y$"; I changed that for you.). Saying $y_n\to y$ in $X$ means just that $||y_n-y||_Y\to0$. Since $Y$ is defined to be a subspace of $X$, the norm on $Y$ is just the restriction of the norm on $X$, so $||y_n-y||_X=||y_n-y||_Y$.

Comment: yes, it is a restriction. Does this then mean that $P(\omega: ||y_{n}-y||_{X} \to 0) = 1$?

Comment: If $A=B$ then anything you can say about $A$ also holds for $B$. That's what equality means

Comment: For this question to be meaningful, you would need to first demonstrate an example of how the first type of convergence might be different from the second. I don't see a difference, it seems to me that you are using the same norm in both cases. This is why I have upvoted the previous comment on $A=B$.

Comment: There should also be a clarification of how you feel the two sigma algebras relate to the problem:  Do you really want to use different probability measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused about the space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P})$ and $(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{B}_\mathrm{X}).$ That the sequence of random objects $(y_n)$ converges to $y$ almost surely *signifies* that there exists a null set $\mathcal{N}$ in $\mathscr{F}$ such that for $\omega$ **not** in $\mathcal{N},$ the sequence of vectors $(y_n(\omega))$ converge to $y(\omega).$ Now, since $\mathrm{Y}$ is a subset of $\mathrm{X},$ every convergence in $\mathrm{Y}$ is also a convergence in $\mathrm{X},$ this convergence is not restricted or affected by $\mathcal{N}$ or anything of $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P}).$

Comment: Actually, you went from the subspace $\mathrm{Y}$ to the whole $\mathrm{X},$ so $\mathrm{Y}$ need not be closed. I ammend.